# rasa shell command working like rasa train nlu

Tags: rasa

When `rasa shell` command is tried in cmd(windows), it's not starting a chat session.
it's working like `rasa train nlu` where it's testing the given messages.
[I've attached the screenshot of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/581TI.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

rasa shell shows you how nlu does entities extraction and intents classification. In your case the intent that was chosen was affirm with a confidence of 0.437

Comment: Indeed, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to. @shahana-syed if this answers your question, could you accept it as an answer.

Comment: well, my question was... when i entered the `rasa shell` command in the cmd, it's working like `rasa train nlu` command instead of starting a chat session.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. Then, followed the steps given below to resolve it.

1. run the command 'rasa interactive' in the terminal.
2. Then, run the command ' rasa shell' in the terminal.

Afterwards, the command worked as expected for me. Thank you.