# 'rasa shell' does not intiate a chat session as expected

Tags: chatbot, rasa

The command 'rasa shell' is supposed to start a chat session in the terminal itself upon its execution according to the [documentation](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/command-line-interface/#:%7E:text=(default%3A%20False)-,rasa%20shell%23,-You%20can%20use). But in my case, it's acting as given in the below image.

[image]

But the output is supposed to be a 2-way communication between the bot and the user as given below.

```
Your input -> hi
<Bot's response to 'hi'>
Your input -> something
<Bot's response to 'something'>
```

May I know what the reason for the above matter is? (Please note that I noticed a similar question to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63117785/rasa-shell-command-working-like-rasa-train-nlu)). Since I found it not descriptive enough, I have posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if:

1. There aren't any redundant intent names in domain.yaml file.
2. There aren't any missing quotation marks in responses.